# 2 responsive promo's columns on frontpage Magento RWD

Tags: magento-1.9, css, rwd-theme

how do i make 2 responsive promo columns instead of the default 3?

[image]

I see this code which makes the 3 responsive pomps/banners on the frontpage:

```
@include bp(min-width, $bp-medium + 1) {

.promos span {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.promos strong {
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Config: Three columns + flexible gutter */
// Container: 480 - (2 * 30 trim wide) = 420
// Math: (420 - (2 * 10 gutter)) / 3 items = 133.333333333
body .promos > li {
    float: left;
    width: percentage(133.333333333 / 420);
    margin-right: percentage(10 / 420);
}

.promos > li:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the numbers for the gutter and trim are still the default then you should make the width of each banner percentage(200/420) (based on the commented Math formula).

You might want to change .promos > lin:nth-child(3n)  to .promos > lin:nth-child(2n).

Then Off course you need to make necessary changes in the html code in the cms

Comment: but where is `Container: 480` coming from? I don't understand. For now i did just the width of the `<li>` is `width: 50%;`

Comment: 480 is min width where the trim(space between the content on the page and browser) is 30px anything smaller and the trim becomes 15px. So 480 is used as the base width - 2 x 30(the trim width) and that give 420 which is the space that is available for the banners. 50% would give you 2 columns but they wouldn't be structured the same way. the width should be at 47.6% to make similar to what is it is now